# getting session object from EntityManager in petclinic jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

All of the code related to this question is in the hyperlinks below.

I want to access a session object in the [PetController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/PetController.java) file from the [spring petclinic sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic).  I have my application configured to use jpa.

Here is what I want to add to one of the methods in `PetController.java`:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
```

My question is how do I set up the `entityManager` so that it is organized centrally and connected to everything in the application to which it needs to be connected?

I found [this example of EntityManager in petclinic's JpaVetRepositoryImpl.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/repository/jpa/JpaVetRepositoryImpl.java).  It uses the syntax:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

But the `EntityManager` does not seem to be called from [VetController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/VetController.java).

I need to call the `session` object, and thus likely the `entitymanager`, from PetController.java. (For those interested, this is a file coming in from the user through a web form, but I do not want to confuse this posting by making it too complicated.  I just want a simple answer to how can I get a `session` object in `PetController.java` using jpa.) What syntax do I use in `PetController.java`?  And what other changes do I need to make elsewhere in the application in order for the `entityManager` and `sessions` to be managed centrally for the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code is organized like this in the sample project is because all persistence code would be better suited in the `petclinic.model` package which contains the project's DAOs (data access objects) the classes with the `xxxRepository` naming convention. The job of the controller is to simply route HTTP requests to business logic and should be kept slim (logic-wise). For your example you might be better off creating a new DAO and service class, maybe called `FileService` and `FileRepository`, along with their corresponding implementations (you can use existing classes in the sample for examples). Once these classes are created you could include the `FileService` in any controllers that needed it. For the `PetController` the flow of your logic would look something like this `PetController -> FileService -> FileRepository.saveFile()`. If you wanted to centralize the entity manager I would only suggest doing it for a generic DAO class that the other DAOs descend from and not including the entity manager in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid accessing session object directly, and use injected EJB (PetRepository) instead.
All your database/jpa business logic must lie inside EJB methods, which are transactional by default.